# Copy each row from sheet1 into two rows in sheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

I have a CSV sheet, a product feed. I want to copy every row from that feed into a new sheet but with two rows there for each in the original. Applied to this data in sheet1:

```
Product 1,data,more_data
Product 2,data,more_data
Product 3,data,more_data
```

I use these formulae:

sheet2 row 2 = `='sheet1'!A2`
sheet2 row 3 = `='sheet1'!A2`

and then pull them down, with this result (ie it skips every even row):

```
Product 1,data,more_data
Product 1,data,more_data
Product 3,data,more_data
Product 3,data,more_data
Product 5,data,more_data
```

But what I would like in sheet2 is:

```
Product 1,data,more_data
Product 1,data,more_data
Product 2,data,more_data
Product 2,data,more_data
Product 3,data,more_data
Product 3,data,more_data
```

Is there a formula to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet1!A"&(MOD(ROW(),2)+ROW())/2)
```

Comment: you beat me to it. ;)

Comment: That solved the other problem but now it is saying "Invalid Cell Reference Error" is there something else I need to change?

Comment: I got it working now, the invalid reference had something to do with the sheet name.

How can I make it so it skips row 1? because that's the header row.

Comment: And if I want to get 3 rows instead of 2? replacing the 2's with 3's didn't seem to work (:

Answer (score 0):

=INDIRECT("sheet1!A"&(MOD(ROW();2)+ROW())/2)

This worked for me! But what if I want 3 rows instead of 2?